# Grab dynamically a cell in excel

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I need to grab dynamically a cell value, I can do it with several vlookup but it is really dirty, so I did a MATCH() to grab an index of line in an array, and I want to use this index as dynamic row in my formula.

my goal is to grab for instance the value of cell H2 where "2" is grabbed dynamically from another tab

Example :

```
lets say my column tab.A1 contains
Index 2

Column H contains
1 Nicolas
2 Nico
3 Ni
```

i tried several ways, all failed

```
=Htab.$A$1
=eval(Htab.$A$1)
=INDIRECT("H"&tab.$A$1)
=CONCAT("H",tab.$A$1)
=eval(concat("H,tab.$A$1))
```

each time i have this :

```
returns #NAME?
```

I d expect the exact value grabbed in H2 as my index is 2, so here in example i d like value "Nico"

EDIT : 
I just tried

```
=INDEX(tab,h,$A$1)
```

and it is still making same error, but i'm not so sure about my use of this function

Comment: Are you using libre office? I'd just use INDEX here.

Comment: yes I am using libreoffice, I didnt tried index so far, I check doc!

Comment: I edited my post with an index attempt, not sure that I use or understand it properly